# Developer console showing a class in error message which does not exist

Tags: apex, developer-console

Developer console is showing a error while saving an apex class. The error message shows about a class file  that was already deleted and no longer exists in the org.

Comment: Sara, can you explain what error you are getting ? does the apex class you are trying to save has any reference to the deleted class ? a screenshot would be better.

Comment: A full screenshot will also help.

Comment: I can share the screenshot later but there is no dependency as i am able to save changes in editor but not in dev console. I could not have even deleted the class if it had reference.

Comment: I've encountered this bug recently, it's really annoying. It was showing an error in a managed class which I hadn't (couldn't actually) altered so I have no idea why it was showing this error.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and it got resolved as soon we got into winter 15.

Answer (score 0):

The developer console uses [container](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_metadatacontainer.htm) to save classes to an org. My guess is that you had the class open and edited at some point in time, then it got deleted and now the workspace in the developer console is confused. Probably the same for the managed class.

Try Workspace -> New Workspace, then try to open your class again and save. A new workspace will also use a new container, so hopefully it will get rid of your issue.